# DefaultModelBinder code not getting called for MVC Remote Validation Calls

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, defaultmodelbinder, remote-validation

I have a DefaultModelBinder which I have inherited from and I have tried overriding the BindModel call and OnPropertyValidating call.

However when using ASP.NET MVC's built in Remote validation, when the controller action gets called it bypasses my DefaultModelBinder and so it doesn't bind/validate how I want it to.

I have registered it in my global.asax, any ideas?

Comment: I have tried using POST and GET attributes for this remote validation call, it also bypasses my custom DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider I set to revalidate, setup in my global.asax

Comment: If you added relevant code snippets, it would be easier to investigate this issue.